# SQL Renaming NULL for null values and rollup

Tags: sql, rollup

I'm trying to make a dashboard to show open tickets and who they are assigned to, by priority. The data set looks like:

```
|-------------------------|
|  Assigned  |  Priority  |
|-------------------------|
|  JOE       |  Low       |
|  JOE       |  Medium    |
|  MARY      |  High      |
|            |  Medium    |
|  TIM       |  Low       |
|  Mary      |  High      |
```

The report I'm trying to get is:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  Employee  |  Low   |   Medium   |   High   |   Total   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Total      |   2    |     2      |    2     |     6     |
| Unassigned |   0    |     1      |    0     |     1     |
|  MARY      |   0    |     0      |    2     |     2     |
|  JOE       |   1    |     1      |    0     |     2     |
|  TIM       |   1    |     0      |    0     |     1     |
```

I can get it all, with this query

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Assigned is null then 'Unassigned' Else Assigned End Employee
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Low
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS High
    ,   count(Priority) AS Total
FROM table
GROUP BY Assigned WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Assigned ASC
```

This way however, it is renaming anything that was NULL to Unassigned. This is perfect to give me the Unassigned values that don't have anyone in the Assigned field, however my Total column is also showing Unassigned. How do I rename that to Total?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your RDBMS: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. ?

Comment: I'm not completely understanding your question?  You're `Total` column should be showing a count for each record, not the word `Unassigned`.  Also, you can change your `CASE` statement to just `COALESCE(Assigned,'Unassigned')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [GROUPING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/255cd/4)

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Assigned) = 1) THEN 'Total'
        When Assigned is null then 'Unassigned' 
        Else Assigned End Employee
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Low
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Priority = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS High
    ,   count(Priority) AS Total
FROM table1
GROUP BY Assigned WITH ROLLUP
--DER BY Assigned ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/255cd/4/0)**:

```
|   EMPLOYEE | LOW | MEDIUM | HIGH | TOTAL |
|------------|-----|--------|------|-------|
| Unassigned |   0 |      1 |    0 |     1 |
|        JOE |   1 |      1 |    0 |     2 |
|       MARY |   0 |      0 |    2 |     2 |
|        TIM |   1 |      0 |    0 |     1 |
|      Total |   2 |      2 |    2 |     6 |
```